# Do I need to do a repeated measures ANOVA?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, biostatistics

I was told my thesis advisor that I might need to do a repeated measures ANOVA because I sampled the same [transects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transect) over time and my observations are technically not independent. However, everything I have read says that you do repeated measures when you have repeated measurments of each subject, not transect.

More Details: Basically, I had line transects set up in 3 separate areas (ML,MP,NWC).I had 6 transects in ML, 2 in NWC, and 6 in MP. I sampled these transects repeatedly throughout the summer looking for horseshoe crabs. I have now compiled all the transect data by area, and so when I analyze my data its location is either ML, MP, or NWC.

What I want to do is compare horseshoe crab abundance among each of the 3 areas and to compare the prosomal width of the horseshoe crabs in the 3 areas.

Comment: Please explain more about your experimental design and question and what you mean by "transect". I don't think you can expect useful advice without more context.

Comment: Are you examining changes over time in abundance or prosomal width, or simply interested in mean values over all observation times? Were there any experimental manipulations whose effects you are trying to evaluate?

Comment: At this point, I am interested in mean values over all observation times. There were no experimental manipulations. Whenever I encountered a horseshoe crab, I measured it, recorded its sex, estimated its age, and % fouling.